# Android Wifi Direct Service Discovery Bonjour Service

Tags: android, service-discovery, wifip2p

https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html

I implement codes above to achieve service discovery. There was some problem about handle services and I periodically stop and start both service discovery and adding local service (about 1 second). I monitor logs of discovery but there is something confusing. Sometimes devices discover services for about 20-30 seconds every cycle of stop and start but sometimes it stops finding for about 3-5 minutes. I have no idea in which conditions it can discover easily and in which condition it can't. I also tried all of wakelock, wifilock and multicastlock but they didn't effect anything. I think some functionality of wifi sleep sometimes. Any idea to solve this? It work perfectly for a while and then sleep for a while and repeat.

Comment: I have also experienced this behavior, and have never seen a fix for it other than resetting the wifi adapter.

Comment: How do you reset wifi adapter? using setWifiEnabled()?

Comment: No I mean swiping from the top of the screen, and manually disabling and reenabling wifi. There must be a way to do it programmatically, I just never looked into it.

Comment: I also tried this and I think it has a bit affect on discovery performance but is not a stable solution. Sometimes still don't discover after this. If it would solve the problem, I could find a way to do it programmatically. Thanks for your response but I don't understand why it don't work properly. It should not be so hard.

Comment: I honestly don't think you are going to find a satisfying solution here. I think there is a lot of bugs in network service discovery in Android in both Wifi and Wifi Direct. For instance, if you try to switch and do discovery with plain old wifi, you find that discovery works, but only for the service name on devices <= 7.0. By that I mean that you can find service names, but not the info. I would suspect that there is a similar bug in the Wifi Direct implementation that Google just has no interest in fixing.